# Android: How do I create a modal tooltip that should be shown only when app is launched for the first time?

Tags: android, xml

I have a button in my `ConstraintLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clickBtn"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#0F9D58"
        android:text="Click Me"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now I want to show a tooltip when the app is launched for the first time. The tooltip should be exactly like the image below:

[image: This should be my screen]

This tooltip should disappear automatically after the first few seconds. How do I proceed to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the number of app starts as shared preference for example. If its 0 than you can show your dialog.

Comment: That's fine, but how do I create the modal hint box?

Comment: Therefore you could use https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView for example